# I want to start number from 001 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Booking class I have specified number to start from. The code is like this

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
MAGIC_NUMBER = 001 # order ref start from 001 to add some obscurity
```

I have function to generate booking number like this

```
def generate_ref_sequence
    count =  Booking.new_today.count
    self.ref = "#{market}#{Date.today.strftime("%y%m%d")}#{"%d" % (MAGIC_NUMBER+count+1)}"

  end
```

There are no errors in generating the sequence. But I want **HK131220009** But I get **HK1312209**. I want to generate **001, 002, 003** then **010, 011, 012** Then **099** then **100** then **101....** and so on.

Comment: `"%03d" % 1` use this to format the number as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `%d` to `%03d` will fix your problem.

Or you may use `%s` and with `(MAGIC_NUMBER+count+1).to_s.rjust(3, '0')`